# Printing SQL query to PDF file

Tags: java, mysql, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to create PDF files in Java. Now I have a task to print SQL queries to PDF files. I've found a solution on Google and tried it with my code. Compilation is fine but when I proceed to create the PDF file it throws an exception error.

Here is my code:

For copying of String array:

```
 public static String[][] append(String[][] a, String[][] b){
     String[][] result = new String[a.length + b.length][];
     System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
     System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
     return result;
 }
```

For generating the table cells on pdf file

```
public static void drawTable(PDPage page,PDPageContentStream contentStream,float y,float margin,String[][] content)throws IOException{
        final int rows = content.length;
        final int cols = content[0].length;
        final float rowHeight = 20.0f;
        final float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth()-(2.0f*margin);
        final float tableHeight = rowHeight*(float)rows;
        final float colWidth = tableWidth/(float)cols;
        final float cellMargin = 2f;
        //draw rows
        float nexty = y;
        for(int i=0;i<=rows;i++){
            //contentStream.drawLine(margin, nexty, margin+tableWidth,nexty);
            contentStream.moveTo(margin,nexty);
            contentStream.lineTo(margin+tableWidth,nexty);
            contentStream.stroke();
            nexty -= rowHeight;
        }
        //draw cols
        float nextx = margin;
        for(int i=0;i<=cols;i++){
            //contentStream.drawLine(nextx,y,nextx,y-tableHeight);
            contentStream.moveTo(nextx,y);
            contentStream.lineTo(nextx,y-tableHeight);
            contentStream.stroke();
            nextx += colWidth;
        }
        //Add strings
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD,6);
        float textx = margin + cellMargin;
        float texty = y - 15.0f;
        for(final String[] aContent : content){
            for(String text : aContent){
                //String text = content[i][j];
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(textx, texty);
                contentStream.showText(text);//Error points here
                contentStream.endText();
                textx += colWidth;
            }
            texty -= rowHeight;
            textx = margin + cellMargin;
         }
    }
```

For recovering data and launching PDF conversion

```
 private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {    

    int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Proceed to generate report for user '"+uName+"'?","Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (x == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION){
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM invoice";//Static for testing purposes
        String[][] content = {{"invoiceNumber","amount","issueDate","ticketNumber","userAccount"}};
        try{
            conn = getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                String[][] data = {{rs.getString("invoiceNumber"),
                rs.getString("amount"),
                rs.getString("issueDate"),
                rs.getString("ticketNumber"),
                rs.getString("userAccount")}};
                content = append(content,data);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(adminRequests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
                try{
                    if(ps != null){
                        ps.close();
                }
                    if(conn != null){
                        conn.close();
                }
                    }catch(SQLException e){
                        Logger.getLogger(adminRequests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }
        try{
            PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font,12);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(30, 700);
            contentStream.showText( "Sales Report" );
            contentStream.endText();

            drawTable(page, contentStream,690,30,content);//Also an Error here
            contentStream.close();
            doc.save("C:\\Users\\Ellie Reyes\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ForTu\\Queries\\"+txtFileName.getText()+"");
            doc.close();
            System.out.println("PDF generated");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(adminRequests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Error

```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:318)    at
> org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:418)
>   at fortu.adminRequests.drawTable(adminRequests.java:113)    at
> fortu.adminRequests.jButton1MouseClicked(adminRequests.java:400)  at
> fortu.adminRequests.access$000(adminRequests.java:30)     at
> fortu.adminRequests$1.mouseClicked(adminRequests.java:165)    at
> java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)    at
> javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
> java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
> java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)  at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
> java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)     at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>   at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)    at
> java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
> java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
> java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
> java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
> java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>   at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
> java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll just add it to the question

Comment: I've done a quick google-search in relation with you problem ... It seems that the error may be caused by a character that is not correctly configured in the desired font. https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/58 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3152

Comment: Have you tried changing the selected font in line `contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD,6);`?

Comment: Tried setting it to TIMES_ROMAN, still have the same problem

Comment: Try with a simpler code. Print just a PDF with "Hello World" testing with diferent fonts. Also you are not trying to print SQL Queries, you are trying to print the RESULT, the data recovered from de DB not the queries themself. Your text is a bit confusing.

Comment: I've already tested the API,and also sorry about that what I mean is the ResultSet to be printed on pdf file

Comment: is `text` not null?

Comment: It shouldn't be null, text is getting its value on content[][]

Comment: But I really suspect that the problem is on that part.

Comment: @Shirwyn put out log messages / use a debugger... I looked at PDFont.java:318 and the NPE comes out only if `text`is null.